# how to make phpPgAdmin not accessible for public

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter, centos6

I have a web app developed by CodeIgniter and for the database using PostgreSQL and the problem is [www.example.com/phpPgAdmin/](http://www.example.com/phpPgAdmin/) is accessible to public and that makes my database insecure.
so I am asking if it possible to make it inaccessible for everyone I've been looking for an answer for so long (maybe I'm asking the wrong question) my VPS running on Centos 6

Comment: Inaccessible for *everyone* or everyone except you? (e.g. do you actually need phpPgAdmin)

Comment: except me if it possible that will be great

Comment: Simplest way is to just add Apache access controls to an .htaccess file in the /phpPgAdmin/ directory - something like `Require all denied` followed by `Require ip {your IP address}` ... that does assume you're using Apache as opposed to something like Nginx - and that your IP address is relatively static: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: thanks for your help sir but please can you be more specific because I am not familiar with htaccess lets say if I want to deny every request for .txt files how it could be done